# Async callback for multiple loops in Swift 3

Tags: swift, multithreading, asynchronous

In one of the project I'm working on, I'm scheduling multiple notifications for different items in my database. Here's some code :

```
func setupNotifications() {
   for medecine in medecineList! {
        if !medecine.whichDaysArray.contains(Medecine.Days.EveryDay.rawValue) {           
            for day in medecine.whichDaysArrayDate {
                for fTime in medecine.frequencyTimeDateArray {
                    self.createNotificationsForUniqueDays(parsedMedecine: medecine, parsedDay: day, parsedFTime: fTime)
                }   
            }
        }
        else {
            for fTime in medecine.frequencyTimeDateArray {
                self.createNotificationsForEveryDay(parsedMedecine: medecine, parsedFTime: fTime)
            }
        }
    }
    self.callback()
}

func createNotificationsForEveryDay(parsedMedecine: Medecine, parsedFTime: Date) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        // Create the notification
    }
}
```

As you can see I deliberately put the function that handles creating the notifications on an async thread. The problem is that I'd like to call the method `callback()` when every async task has finished doing its job. I have no clue how to achieve this.

Any help, is appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Method `createNotificationsForEveryDay` should have a block as parameter. In that block I would check to see if I processed the last item in `frequencyTimeDateArray` and if I did then I would call `self.callback()`.

Comment: I can't do that unfortunately. Because as you can see I have multiple loops. One item in the frequencyTimeDateArray can be utilised many times depending on how many items there are in the whichDatesArray. And I cannot use that logic for this last array because there is a else/if clause before that. In the end I want my callback function to be able to retrieve all the pending notifications.